# How can I make the leading flutter date icon clickable and selectable widget?

Tags: date, flutter, dart

Below is my flutter code and I would like to make the leading calendar icon launch a calendar widget for date selection in the last textfield just before the raised button as marked below in code.

** widget starts inside stateful class**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var db = DBHelper();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 50, right: 50),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark), hintText: 'nickname'),
                controller: nameController,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.date_range), hintText: 'date created'),
                controller: otherController,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  db.saveAssets(Asset(
                      name: nameController.text,
                      other: otherController.text));
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyAssetsList()),
                  );
                },
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, right: 18),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                splashColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                child: const Text(
                  'Save',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more solution.

If you want only the calendar icon to be tapable (while still having similar design to the one you've provided):

```dart
Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('Yay!');
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Date Created',
                      ),
                      readOnly: true, // Or wrap the input with AbsorbPointer if you do not want the field to get highlighted by taping on it
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

If you want to let the user input the date by typing - just remove the readOnly attribute from the input.